# Display all the files while selecting a folder using askdirectory() in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In Tkinter, I have to just select the folder in which my files are present. I am doing it using `filedialog.askdirectory()`.
Is it also possible to view the files present in the folder in UI ?

Comment: Do you mean to show the filenames inside the selected folder by `askdirectory()`?

Comment: Yes, I want the filenames

Comment: You might want to start by `import os` and then `path = filedialog.askdirectory(...)` then `files = os.listdir(path)` and then `tk.Label(text=files)`, or if you know which file extension to be exactly picked then you can also use `from glob import glob` and then `txt = glob(f'{path}/*.txt')`. This will pick all the txt files from the directory. Note that all this will return a `list` of files.

Comment: Why not use one of the other file GUIs? `askopenfilename` for example which will show both folders and files.

Comment: I cannot select folder using askopenfilename

Answer (score 0):

Use this function by provide a file extension (any extension should be fine)!
file_extension="niff"

```
def displayall ( file_extension):   
    
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    
    # get data file names, all the file extention
    os.chdir(path)
    
    all_fNames0 = glob.glob(path + '/**/*.{}'.format(file_extension), recursive=True)
    print("Total number of files:", len(all_fNames0))
    print("All file names:", all_fNames0)
```

Hope this helps!